# How can I test and handle a #Func! error from within a query?

Tags: ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2003

I have an Access query that has a some what complex field on it.  Basically, I'm searching for a certain value, based on other derived criteria.  The function either works, or it gives a `#Func!` error. There are a few reasons why I may get an error.  That is fine, because in those cases I want to return `Null`.

How can I test and handle a `#Func!` error from within a query?  Also, I tried to wrap the expression in an `IsError()` method, and handle that case.  That still didn't work.

Comment: What causes the `#Func!` error?

Comment: HansUp: In essence, I'm trying to construct a mid.  However, the end bounds isn't always calculated correctly due to some other criteria.  In short, this should have to do with an InStr() failure.  But, that's ok.  Instead of creating a function that is a mile long, I know which instances will have errors. I just want to filter out that case.  Can I do this in a query, or will I have to use VBA?

Comment: It's still too vague for me, so I'll just suggest an `IIf()` expression: `IIf(<not condition which triggers error>, <do something>, <do something else>)`  However, I have no idea how that could translate to the specifics of your situation.  :-(

Comment: Yeah, that can be the problem with Access.  If you use the IIf technique to much, you end up with an incomprehensible mesh of spaghetti SQL.  This is a one-off data extraction routine and it's already REALLY long.  I'd rather not have to make it any larger, if I can just test for an error case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the optimal solution, however, my hope is that the "higher powers that be" within Microsoft that manage Microsoft Access understand exception handling and would provide some way of testing and handling/ignoring errors, where appropriate.

Regardless, in my case I found a hack to the problem.  I save the query just as it was and I exported it to a table.  Since this was a one-off exercise, I was able to extract the necessary data and then filter out all `Null` values from the newly created table.

It worked, but it feels like a really poor hack.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, you are using Instr with a field that may or may not be null, and that is causing the problem, you can either select only those fields that are not null, or concatenate an empty string with the field.

```
 SELECT Mid(AField & "",Instr(Afield & "","x")) FROM Table
```

Answer (score -1):

OMGGGGG I know im 6 years late but This is the first time I'm posting on a blog because I actually solved the issue!! You have no idea how excited I am. OK so it turns out this is exactly what I was trying to do: Mid(AField,Instr(Afield,"x")). In my case I knew the InStr function did not always find x in Afield, and in those cases ideally I wanted a Null. But What it actually returns is a 0. In access, functions like Right, Left and Mid CANNOT "START" AT 0, They must start at 1 (or -1 I suppose). Which is what is causing the #Func! error!

One solution....if your Instr fuction=0 do one thing other wise do something else.

If I think of another solution, I let you know.

Comment: This is actually not a blog at all. Please review the help files.

Comment: Sorry to rain on your parade, but this was the first answer in 2012.